# select-string how to only return first match line in first file

Tags: powershell, select-string

I am searching a directory for pattern, switches are -SimpleMatch -List. But it returns a list of files. How to do it to return only first file and first line in it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use the `Select-Object` command to return the first match. You don't need to use `Get-ChildItem` since you can specify the path parameter in Select-String. The `Select-String` command returns `MatchInfo` object which contains the matching line and also the name of the file.

```
$m = Select-String -Pattern get -Path *.ps1 -list -SimpleMatch | select-object -First 1
$m.Line
$m.Path
```

Comment: thanks. Also I find that combination of -List and -Quiet achieving same effect.